# Priority condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I like to select a row by priority on MySQL. I don't know if it is possible, but see the example below:

```
id name
1  John
2  Doe
3  Mary
4  Jhonny
```

Supposing that I don't know the ID, but by a specific reason, I need select by priority: 3, 2, 1... On this case, the MARY will be selected (#3). But if I will need select by order 5, 2, 1, the DOE will be selected (#2).

Ok, I can do it by using IN(5, 2, 1). The problem is that if I don't have any results (like IN(5, 6, 7)), I need at least one row (don't matter what).

For instance: select 5, 6, 7... nothing found... then, select the first found (like JOHN).

It's possible?

Bye!

**Edit**: I just thought of this solution, but I do not know how fast it should be, but it works well. Accept a response that has a better benchmark for nobody lose.

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`id`, '5,6,7') DESC
```

Comment: Could the priority order be something like `2, 4, 1, 3` and produce `Doe` as the result? Or would `Jhonny` be an acceptable result?

Comment: If don't fit on priority, any row can be used, whichever comes first and that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY 
(CASE id 
WHEN 5 THEN 1
WHEN 6 THEN 2
WHEN 7 THEN 3
ELSE id+10
END)
LIMIT $some_limit;
```

The trick is make use on `order by`

So, the matching id of 5 will give the priority 1,
matching id of 6 will give the priority 2,
matching id of 7 will give the priority 3,
otherwise, least id will return

*assuming you are using **unsigned** for id*

Comment: But if you do not have any of the IDs in the list and your $some_limit is 10 you will get first 10 results, not only 1 as he wants.

Comment: OP wants at least of one row, so, it will still match

Answer (score 0):

At first you need remap ID column to order column, let's do it with help of special union (first column is you id, second is order instruction):

```
 SELECT 5 as ID, 1 as ord
 UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 2
 UNION ALL SELECT 1 , 3
```

Is it clear?
if so - let's do full example:

```
SELECT m.* from MyTable m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
       SELECT 5 as ID, 1 as ord
       UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 2
       UNION ALL SELECT 1 , 3
    ) o ON m.ID = o.ID
ORDER BY  COALESCE(o.ord, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.username, id
FROM tbluser U
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`username`, 'Tester') DESC, username ACS
```

This priorities (gives first) the "Tester" and then sort it A-Z